# Multiple pgfplots with common y-axis

Tags: pgfplots, subfloats, tikz-graphs

[image: Graphs with common y-axis]As a part of manuscript, I have to plot multiple graphs whose x and y axes ranges are the same. I am using subflot along with tikzpicture. My question is, since the range of values of the both axes are same, y-axis can be eliminated and plot all graphs side-by-side with individual x-axis but common y-axis. Each graph has scatter plot and line plot (Actual and fitted data). The manual mentions stack plots but that is not what I want. Please help me.

```
    \documentclass[3p, dvipsnames]{elsarticle}
    \usepackage{pgfplots,pgfplotstable}
    \usetikzlibrary{plotmarks}
    \pgfplotsset{every  tick/.style={thick,}}
    \pgfkeys{/pgf/number format/set thousands separator = }
    \pgfplotsset{scaled x ticks= true}
    \pgfplotsset{compat=1.13}
    \usepgfplotslibrary{patchplots,colormaps, colorbrewer}
    \usepackage{subfig}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    %......................................................................................
    \begin{document}
    \begin{figure*}[tb]
        \centering
        \subfloat[][]{
            \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.68, font = \large]
\begin{axis}[
            ylabel={$y'$},
            xlabel={$y$},
            ]
            %..............................................................................................................................
            \addplot[mark = none, line width=1.25pt, color =black][domain = 25:350, samples= 50]{(1.114938029*x)+(-16.01)};
            \legend{$\, Y_1$}
            \end{axis}
            \end{tikzpicture}\label{fig:label1}
        }
        \subfloat[][]{
            \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.68, font = \large]
            \begin{axis}[
            ylabel={$y'$},
            xlabel={$ y $},
            ]
            %..............................................................................................................................
            \addplot[mark = none, line width=1.25pt, color = RedOrange][domain = 25:350, samples= 50]{(0.96*x)+(5.98)};
            \legend{$\, Y_2$}
            \end{axis}
            \end{tikzpicture}\label{fig:label2}
        }
        \subfloat[][]{
            \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.68, font = \large]
            \begin{axis}[
            ylabel={$y'$},
            xlabel={$ y$},
            ]
            %..............................................................................................................................
            \addplot[mark = none, line width=1.25pt, color = Cerulean][domain = 25:350, samples= 50]{(0.96*x)+(6.00)};
            \legend{$\, Y_3$}
            \end{axis}
            \end{tikzpicture}\label{label3}
        }
        \caption{My caption.}\label{figlabel}
    \end{figure*}
    
    \end{document}
```

Comment: Hi, I am not sure I understand what you want to obtain. Maybe you can add an hand-made sketch of the desired result?

Comment: Yes - you need to draw what you want. Also please clean up your code a little. There  are many things not relevant to the problem like `filecontents` the `\caption` and more.

Comment: @Rmano, added a sketch. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want it like in your image, it no longer make sense to use `subfig`. Here is one way to do it:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\pgfplotsset{legend pos=north west, ymin=-10, ymax=400}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}[
name=plot1,
ytick pos=left,
xlabel={$y$}, ylabel={$y'$},
]
\addplot[very thick][domain=25:350, samples=2]{(1.114938029*x)+(-16.01)};
\legend{$\, Y_1$}
\end{axis}

\begin{axis}[
name=plot2, at={(plot1.south east)},
ytick=\empty,
xlabel={$y$},
]
\addplot[orange, very thick][domain=25:350, samples=2]{(0.96*x)+(5.98)};
\legend{$\, Y_2$}
\end{axis}

\begin{axis}[
name=plot3, at={(plot2.south east)},
ytick=\empty,
xlabel={$y$},
]
\addplot[teal, very thick][domain=25:350, samples=2]{(0.96*x)+(6.00)};
\legend{$\, Y_3$}
\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Three connected graph with common y axis]

Comment: Thanks a bunch hpekristiansen, I appreciate quick response. I have total of 4 groups with each group consists of 3 plots. Since this is a part of research paper, I need to use subfig (or any other thing, subfloat?) so that I can refer them in the text. Thanks again. This is an amazing solution.

Comment: @hpekristiansen How can I add some horizontal space between each axis when proceeding in this manner? (I still want the plots to be vertically aligned)

Comment: You can use e.g. `at={($ (1cm,0cm) + (plot1.south east) $)}` with `\usetikzlibrary{calc}`.