# Overlay plots (picture-in-picture, PIP) in pgfplots

Tags: pgfplots, overlap

I would like to draw another chart over an existing one to take advantage of an unused area. I'm getting close to what I wanted by using a negative `baseline` and `hskip`. Unfortunately, the latter messes up the horizontal alignment, which could be fixed by using a box, perhaps? Also, controlling the final position is done by eyeballing.

Anyhow, is there a more elegant way to do what I'm after?
I've Googled extensively, but it appears like plot overlays were never discussed before.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepackage[show frame]{geometry}  % show text edges
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[t!]\centering
  \begin{tikzpicture}\begin{axis}
    \addplot+ [domain=0:360, samples=101, mark=none] {sin(x)};
  \end{axis}\end{tikzpicture}    
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[t!]\centering
  \begin{tikzpicture}\begin{axis}
    \addplot+ [domain=0:360, samples=101, mark=none] {sin(x)};
  \end{axis}\end{tikzpicture}\hskip -7cm
  \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=-1cm]\begin{axis}[width=120pt]
    \addplot+ [domain=0:360, samples=101, mark=none] {sin(2*x)/2};
  \end{axis}\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\hfill  % so the figures move up
\end{document}
```

[image: misaligned overlayed charts]

Comment: You can take a look [at this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/595700/) I asked in the past.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want something placed relative to something else, then it would be a lot easier to keep it in the same `tikzpicture`. Here is an example where the second plot is place at a specific coordinate in the first plot:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot+ [domain=0:360, samples=101, mark=none] {sin(x)};
\coordinate (subplot) at (20,-0.9);
\end{axis}
\begin{axis}[width=120pt, at=(subplot), tick label style={font=\small}]
\addplot+ [domain=0:360, samples=101, mark=none] {sin(2*x)/2};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: One plot inside an other]

You can also just place the second plot at some coordinate in the TikZ picture or relative to the corner of the first plot.

Comment: This is just so awesome. I did find the `at` command just now in the documentation. [Here](https://wikis.ovgu.de/lss/doku.php?id=guide:latex:with_pgf#perfectly_aligning_multiple_axes) they do something even fancier, and use the `name` TikZ keyword (not even mentioned in pgfplots manual). Anyhow, thanks for the helping with this and for the `\coordinate` trick!

Comment: Here is also an example on this site: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/644047/8650